# Getting Red Alert sign while importing FacebookSDK and Hackbook sample code in Eclipse

Tags: android

I am trying to use *facebook Hackbook sample* app for android in eclipse, I have imported facebookSDK and hackbook sample app by using this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ **step 3**, but I am getting **Red Alert Sign** (FacebookSDK & Hackbook) in both why?

Because i have checked:

> I am using Java Compiler 1.6
>
> Getting SDK link in Properties - Android [Hackbook sample]

Comment: @Neurenor I have posted a new question please view this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209252/how-to-make-custom-dob-and-fetch-profile-pic-of-fb-friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it must be the mismatch of jar files.
First of all Delete android.jar from both(Hackbook and FacebookSDK).

Then follow below steps:

Right Click on Project(HAckbook) -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library
and The again Right Click on Project(HAckbook) -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties
do same on Facebook SDK.

and Clean-Build all your projects(Facebook SDK and Hackbook).You are Done.

Comment: sorry buddy for late reply actually whenever i do right click on android.jar files to delete that not getting delete option [in short disable] why?

Comment: you should delete it from project properties. Right Click to Project->Properties->Java Build Path ->Libraries->Remove Android Dependencies library.you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and build your FacebookSDK and Hackbook project, follow below steps:

step-1

Clean your FacebookSDK first.

step-2

and then clean your Hackbook project.

step-3

and then run it.

Comment: he has wrote that he added SDK link in properties.

Comment: @GautamKumar both api level is same or different?

Comment: @GautamKumar once restart your eclipse and then check.

Comment: @GautamKumar you want make custom DOB and fetch profile pic of friends,Right? 

Please kindly asks another question related to your issue,sure you will get if anyone know.